# Tunneling HTTPS traffic via a PUTTY/SSL tunnel with SOCKS

Tags: putty, https, socks-proxy

I have configured a [SOCKS ssh tunnel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvL5H.png) to a remote proxy, and set my Firefox to use `localhost:<port>` as a SOCKS proxy. My intention is to tunnel outgoing HTTP/S connections from my machine via a specific 3rd party server I own (on AWS).

In my testing, HTTP UTLs are forwarded properly (e.g. when I access http://jsonip.com/ from my computer I do get the server's IP)

However, whenever I try to reach an HTTPS address, I get this error:

```
The proxy server is refusing connections
```

How do I debug/fix it?

My PUTTY tunnel config is simply (some random source port number + `dynamic` checked):

[image]

P.S. I'm aware I might need to manually accept SSL certificates. The reason I'm doing this is to resolve [problems using gmail as an outbound SMTP service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013736/how-can-i-avoid-google-mail-server-asking-me-to-log-in-via-browser).

Comment: I haven't used PuTTY in a long time; have you tried with Dymanic instead of Local? I think the way it is now you're only forwarding :80.

Comment: @zmode - Sorry, the screenshot is incorrect, I actually used Dynamic in my real testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to pull this off by switching from PUTTY to command line SSH:

> ssh -D 9998 user@myserver.com

or

> ssh -ND 9998 user@myserver.com

(Not sure which one of these did it)

Comment: I really do not understand why do you use dynamic port, but if it works for you, then fine

Answer (score 0):

> However, whenever I try to reach an HTTPS address, I get this error:
>
> ```
> The proxy server is refusing connections
> ```
>
> How do I debug/fix it?

That means that your `socks proxy server` is set not to connect clients to port `443`. Check its configuration

Comment: How? Do you mean some socks/ssh daemon running on the target (ubuntu) machine, or the PUTTY client (which is also a server)

Comment: The former one, the daemon on Ubuntu machine

Comment: I think this is not the case - check out my answer.